# WCF Service call from ajax(cross domain)

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf

I am trying to call WCF Service from other project using the local address. I have two projects in same solution explorer. One project has the services and the other is a web application where I am using Ajax in javascript to call the WCF Service.
Following is my javascript code,

```
function sclick() {
    alert("m here");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:4780/Service1.svc/myfunction",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8 ",
        dataType: "json",
        success: success,
        error: fail
    })

}

function success(result) {
    alert(result);
   //alert("Success" + result.myfunctionResult);
}

function fail(result) {
    alert("Fail..... " + result.statusText + ": " + result.status);
}
```

flow goes to success function but I get null in result object. URL in ajax part is the URL I got by viewing the service1.svc file in browser.
Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong!
It works fine in same project. But cross domain is not working. When I call the service from other project it returns me null. I gave break point in service. Break point shows proper value but it does not come in my javascript code.

Comment: Have you configured your WCF service too accept cross domain requests?

Comment: I think so.. In app.config file I have given following tags
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain"      crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
Am I correct? or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Is your service configured to support REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't talk to a WCF service out of the box with a regaular Web service call, it is possible but more complicated. see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c896b564-7a9b-423d-a42d-d36c33c46e7d/consume-a-wcf-service-as-a-url

That is because WCF has an "overhead" of data used by the framework. Plus , WCF configuration may differ: It could be REST, SOAP or even Tcp or named pipe.

A more easy approach would be to generate the WCF client:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx

and than
call the client proxy from the ajax, instead of trying to call the server directly.

That is assuming you are running on a .Net web application. 
otherwise, see how to talk to the service directly. This here an example on how to do this with Java:
http://hoonzis.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client.html

And finally, another good answer which was suggested here and was later deleted, is to cofigure the WCF service to support REST API, like so:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be that WCF doesn't support cross domain out of the box unless you enable CORS.

There's a good read with explanation and work around here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx

Another alternative which may be easier for you would be to just drop the WebAPI into whichever project you're using, can do this in WebForms or MVC pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about WCF web service but May be these lines of code which is for regular service , solve your problem

```
          var jsonData = [YOUR JSON PARAMETER];

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: [YOUR WEB SERVICE URL],
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                  
                data: JSON.stringify({ json: jsonData }),
                dataType: "json",                
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function(err) {
                    alert("Error : " + err.d);
                }  
            }); 

            function OnSuccess(data) {
                alert("Success:" + data.d);                       
            }
```

You can do one thing for that just need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin & Access-Control-Allow-Headers in CustomeHeaders your web service web.config file.

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

If you want to allow only for specific domain , you can do that with specific value of domain instead of * value